# Maven error in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have an error in Jenkins when I try to build my maven-project.
I've installed the maven plugin and also configured it. I'm using a pom.xml and the default maven settings.

Can someone help me?

```
Parsing POMs

[maven-plugin] $ 
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/.../org.jenkins-ci.main/maven-plugin"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:266)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:755)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 12 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

The configuration of my job is similar as in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iv3kPZN4DU)  at 2.08

Maven configuration:
[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b6zT.png)

Comment: Add you plugin configuration.

Comment: My plugin just got a "Name" and the "path" where Maven is installed on my server.

Comment: Please add screen :)

Comment: Are you sure that you have `/talend/maven/current/bin/mvn` file which is readable and executable by `jenkins` user?

Comment: I have that file yes. How can I check the maven installation worked?

Comment: When I try to run a prebuild step with maven: (clean & install). I get this error: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory. The POM file is in another path (like in the video)

Comment: Can you check if you have JDK installed and well configed instead of a JRE? Maven need a JDK. Try go to the slave your job running on and run which java.